# Bootstrap: set image center in a container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my page i have a `<div class="container">` that it has to `<div>` , one of them has image and another has tab, i want to set image center of container but i don't know how it's work.

this is my code:

```
<div style="margin: 30px auto;">
    <div class="container" style="margin: 0px auto;">
        <div class="profile-image" style="margin: 50px auto;">
            <img src="images/pro.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="w470px exam" style="margin: 30px auto;">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab-home" data-value="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab-fav" data-value="#fav" data-toggle="tab">Favorites</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab-fr" data-value="#fr" data-toggle="tab">Friends</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab-ex" data-value="#ex" data-toggle="tab">Experience</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab-home" style="margin: 10px;">
                            My Home
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-fav" style="margin: 10px;">
                            My Favorites
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-fr" style="margin: 10px;">
                            My Friends                            </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-ex" style="margin: 10px;">
                            My Experience
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/1/)

at jsfiddle all things is ok but in my page image doesn't center.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Fa: Salam Aji Elham :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
   <div class="profile-image" style="margin: 50px auto;">
```

To:

```
  <div class="profile-image" style="margin:0 auto;">

.profile-image{
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Nothing isn't changed.

Comment: Maybe other Classes or css files effected to this.margin: 0 auto; and text-align:center; is Always useful ... :(